# Explode array in Trino to multiple columns

Tags: presto, trino

I have a column of type `array(varchar)` which looks like this -

| colA |
| --- |
| {"Person1=200", "Person2=150", "Person3=100"} |
| {"Person1=202", "Person2=148", "Person3=99", "Person4=130"} |

The arrays can be of variable length.

I want to explode the arrays so that each element is its own column and `Person1`, `Person2` etc will be the column names.

So the above column should look like this -

| Person1 | Person2 | Person3 | Person4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 150 | 100 | null |
| 202 | 148 | 99 | 130 |

I'm aware of `UNNEST` but it splits the array into rows and I couldn't find the equivalent for columns.

Comment: 1. there is no `array(varchar)` shown in your data if I understand correctly (it should be displayed as `[Person1=200, Person2=150]`) 2. AFAIK Trino/Presto (still) does not support dynamic pivoting so in short - this is not possible.

Comment: 1. `select typeof(col1) from table` gives me `array(varchar)`. I'm not super experienced with trino so not sure why that's the case. 2. Fair enough, thanks.